# Error while adding "Mobclix 6.0.0"

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, mobclix

- I want to integrate Latest iOS 6 supported sdk in the application.
  but when i delete old sdk and add latest sdk "Mobclix SDK 6.0.0" in
  my app then it is giving following error. Will you please explain
  what should i do to fix this?

  ```
  Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:
   objc-class-ref in libMobclix.a(MCEnvironment.o)
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i was not adding "AdSupport" Framework in my application.

**Do not forget to add it as Optional if you want to support iOS 5 also**